# Rails can not connect to redis on openshift

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, openshift, sidekiq

I have openshift apps with installation of redis from [this example](https://github.com/razorinc/redis-openshift-example)
I have these settings for Sidekiq(initializers/sidekiq.rb):

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { path: "#{ENV['OPENSHIFT_GEAR_DIR']}tmp/redis.sock" }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { path: "#{ENV['OPENSHIFT_GEAR_DIR']}tmp/redis.sock" }
end
```

But I have this error If I can use sidekiq:

```
Redis::CannotConnectError (Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (ECONNREFUSED)):
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that Sidekiq is trying to connect to port 6379 on localhost. The OpenShift example you are using sets the port to 0 in the configuration file, so that the server will not listen on any TCP socket.

I think this answers your question: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/228#issuecomment-7618003

Comment: thank you, I change default redis settings to openshift's open port and I set it in sidekiq, it's working perfect.